# Regular expression when reading files javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a situation where I have 3 font files and I read its content in order to find mathes with font name. But the thing is that font names are Wingdings, Wingdings 2, Wingdings 3. And when I have Wingdings font name it matches all 3 files, but I need file that exactly is associated with font name, not all 3 of them. I tried to find it using indexOf method, but it didn't help. The only rational way is to use regular expression, but cannot think of a right one. One more thing need to be mentioned is that I have to pass a parameter into that regExp, something like

```
var regExp = new RegExp('\\^' + fontName + '$\\', 'g');
if (currentFileContent.search(regExp) !== -1) {...}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `var regExp = RegExp('^' + fontName + '$'); if (regExp.test(currentFileContent)) { ... }`.

Comment: Also, you may need to escape the font name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you try to use regex delimiters in a RegExp constructor. You only need `/.../` in the literal notation.

Note you need not escape the start and end of string anchors, they lose their special meaning in the regex then. `\\` matches a single `\`, but it cannot be matched after end of string (`$`).

Also, you can use [`RegExp#test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function to check if the string matches the pattern (note no `g` modifier can be used with it):

```
var regExp = RegExp('^' + fontName + '$'); 
if (regExp.test(currentFileContent)) { ... }
```

If font names contain special characters, use [`escapeRegExp` function from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
function escapeRegExp(string){
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

And then

```
var regExp = RegExp('^' + escapeRegExp(fontName) + '$');
```

And the final note: if the font names appear inside a larger string, and you need to match `Windings` but not `Windings3`, use

```
var regExp = RegExp('\\b' + escapeRegExp(fontName) + '\\b');
```

The `\b` is a word boundary.

**UPDATE**

To make sure you only match a font name that **is not followed by a whitespace (if any) and a digit**, use a `(?!\\s*\\d)` lookahead when declaring a `RegExp`:

```js
var fontName = "Wingding";
var contents = "Font name: Wingding, the other file: Font name: Wingding 2. And so forth. ";
var rExp = RegExp(fontName + '(?!\\s*\\d)');
if (rExp.test(contents)) {
   document.write(fontName + " was found in '<i>" + contents + "</i>'.");
}
```

Comment: Also, `g` makes no sense when you want to match a whole string with your regex.

Comment: a tried, but it mathes all 3 files again. here may be the case where there's a space between Windings 3, not Windings3. and font name is just Windings. maybe check if there's characters after space?

Comment: Then just check for Windings, like `/Windings(?!\s*\d)/.test(file)`.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I pass a variable fontName instead of Windings string here?

Comment: Using `RegExp`: `var regExp = RegExp(fontName + '(?!\\s*\\d)');`

Comment: fun thing, but now using regExp it doesn't work (matches all files) and I did double escaping of backslashes just like you did '(?!\\s*\\d)'

Comment: Please post the file contents, I am trying to help you rather blindly right now.

Comment: It's a wingding.ttf file located in a system fonts directory if you're on windows go c/windows/fonts. I'm using extendscript for reading and copying file contents. File contains a string like: Font name: Wingding, the other file: Font name: Wingding 2. And so forth. Your answer with regExp literal  /Windings(?!\s*\d)/.test(file) worked just fine. But when using new RegExp matched all 3 files... thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!